# How do I uninstall Extreme Download Manager?

Tags: java, download-manager, software-uninstall

How do I  uninstall Extreme Download Manager on Ubuntu 12.04? That means also getting rid of the icon that appears in the Application area of Dash as well as all the Java related stuff that was downloaded with it.

I tried using '`sudo apt-get purge xdman`' but i am not certain that that did the job:(please tell me that i didn't make things worse, PLEASE!).

I was told that xdman was uninstalled but all the Java related stuff is still in the history section of the Ubuntu software center and the extreme download manager icon is still in the app section of Dash. And i want to get rid of that also. I have heard that Java is dangerous because its loaded with spyware etc!

Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879789/i-cant-use-remove-to-uninstall-xtreme-download-manager) better way than both answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is not dangerous. It can be if the application using it was not using it properly thus creating holes and such. That doesn't mean that using Java automatically makes you vulnerable...because it doesn't.

I wouldn't use Java unless I absolutely have to because Java uses a lot of resources to do simple things so I much prefer native applications instead.

With that said, what [Olupot Douglas](https://askubuntu.com/a/421180/72652) said regarding the removal is close.

```
sudo apt-get remove xdman
```

that will remove the xdman package.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

that will remove all unnecessary packages...packages that were installed but are no longer being used by any other packages. This applies to any packages not being used, not just xdman.

```
sudo apt-get purge xdman
or
sudo apt-get remove --purge xdman
```

Purge will remove config files as well as uninstalling the app. If you did this then that is odd that it is still showing xdman content in your dash.

---

Java still being installed after uninstalling xdman is expected because just uninstalling xdman doesn't mean it will also uninstall Java. First, try the autoremove option and if that doesn't remove java then reply here and I will give you some other commands to use. (but autoremove should work)

Comment: as a side note, I would suggest installing uGet. uGet is a native open source download manager for Ubuntu. You can find install instructions for the PPA and DEB files to download at http://ugetdm.com/downloads

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR REPLY. I FOLLOWED ALL YOUR INSTRUCTIONS AND GOT THIS: Unable to locate package xdman. I ALSO REMOVED THE PACKAGE FROM THE DOWNLOAD SECTION BUT THERE IS STILL AN ICON IN THE APPS SECTION OF DASH BUT THE ICON IS BLANK, EMPTY, COLORLESS!!GO FIGURE!I SHALL DOWNLOAD UGET ASAP AFTER THIS PROBLEM IS FIXED.THANKS

Comment: PS--ALL THE JAVA RELATED STUFF IS STILL IN THE HISTORY SECTION OF THE UBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTER. WOULD THAT HAVE ANYTHING TO DO WITH WHY THE BLANK EMPTY XDMAN ICON IS STILL IN THE APPS SECTION OF DASH?

Comment: That is weird that the entry was leftover. The autoremove should have taken care of that so if you haven't ran that then try that. If you have tried it then try running autoremove. Otherwise, install "alacarte" from the Software Center, this app will give you a GUI to edit the Dash entries. Open alacarte, go to the category you need to, right click the blank entry and choose "remove". You can edit other items and categories with this app as well if you want.

Comment: YES!I TRIED ALACARTE AND IT DID THE JOB!TOMORROW I SHALL TRY UGET! MANY THANKS FOR YOUR TIME AND HELP!!!

Answer (score 4):

In 2018 version (and later) the apt-get solution **doesn't** work.

2018 was the version that had to be installed like so:

[image]

and contained an archive with just the `install.sh` script and a `readme` file.

But in the readme file we have the solution:

```
sudo /opt/xdman/uninstall.sh
XDM is successfully removed from your computer
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just delete the xdman directory and uninstall xdm helper plugin in your browser 
To uninstall xdman

```
 sudo apt-get remove xdman
```

To remove the config data as well

```
 sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove xdman
```

**I've never really used or installed it before**