# I can't use "remove" to uninstall xtreme download manager

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I downloaded xtreme download manager from its website.

The archive I downloaded was `xdm-setup-x64.tar.xz`

With the setup comes a `readme.txt` file, I followed it to install.

Now I want to uninstall the xtreme download manager but `sudo apt-get remove xdman` gives me:

```
E: Unable to locate package xdman
```

How can I uninstall it?

Comment: You did not install a .deb package, so you can't uninstall using `apt-get`. Look inside the `readme.txt` if there is some information on how to uninstall.

Comment: No, @ridgy , it only says how to install.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems to be installed completely in `/opt/xdman`, with `xdman.desktop` copied to `/usr/share/applications/`and creating a symbolic link `/usr/bin/xdman`. So, to completely remove/uninstall, you should remove the link, the desktop file and the installation directory:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/xdman
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/xdman.desktop
sudo rm -r /opt/xdman
```

This should do it.

Comment: but I still see the icon. when I search application typing "x".

Answer (score 15):

There is a straightforward answer here now (tested only on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS/elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki though :) )

1. Open Terminal
2. `cd /opt/xdman/`
3. `sudo ./uninstall.sh`

That's all ;)

Answer (score 4):

As written in the `readme.txt` file:

> 5. To uninstall run /opt/xdman/uninstall.sh as root

Running this in terminal uninstalls xdman:

```
sudo /opt/xdman/uninstall.sh
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of an existing answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, but this has one fewer step.