# After uninstalling "Xtreme Download Manager", I still see its icon when I type "X" in search applications

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04

I followed this step mentioned by the app developer in readme note to uninstall it:

> 5. To uninstall run `/opt/xdman/uninstall.sh` as root

I even rebooted to see if it disappears, but it didn't. I tried the solution mentioned in [I can't use "remove" to uninstall xtreme download manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879789/i-cant-use-remove-to-uninstall-xtreme-download-manager)
 but it didn't work either.

Any help appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `sudo rm /usr/share/applications/xdman.desktop` ?

Comment: @Jim I did try that from reading the link I mentioned. It didn't work. It says, "No such file or directory"

Comment: How did you install xdman ? Any tutorial you followed ?

Comment: @Jim i installed it by downloading a zip file from Sourceforge and extract it, saw "readme" file, read it and installed it.

Comment: I would find the file, `sudo find / -type f -name "xdman.desktop"`. This will do a recursive search from `/` directory, which cover all possible folder.

Comment: I would check the zipfile and install/uninstall scripts to see if the .desktop file has a different name and/or gets installed to an unexpected location.

Comment: @user535733 there is nothing much in zip file. Only install.sh and readme file. https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/files/xdm-2018-x64.tar.xz/download u can check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matter got solved after I searched in my Home directory by typing `xdm`.

Delete `xdm.desktop` and that's it.

Comment: There maybe some more xdm-related stuff in *~*, *~/.config* or *~/.local/share* as well you could remove.

Comment: @DKBose I see over 100's of the folder which includes configuration of all old application which I don't use it anymore. Is there a command to remove all old config/unwanted files.

Comment: I suggest you do the removal by hand so you'll be sure. Also, send the deleted files/folders to Trash rather than deleting them permanently. That way, if you make a mistake, you can simply restore the file/folder.